# Can't install firebird adapter for ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, firebird, activerecord-fb-adapter

[image]

My ruby version:
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

Bundler version:
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [i386-mingw32]

I got installed:
railsinstaller-3.2.0.exe
Firebird-2.5.4.26856_0_x64.exe

I think error is somewhere here:

```
def read_firebird_registry
require 'win32/registry'
Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open('SOFTWARE\Firebird Project\Firebird Server\Instances'
 , Win32::Registry::KEY_READ)
 do |reg|
return reg.read_s('DefaultInstance') rescue nil
 end
end
```

But i dont know how to fix it and how to install gem with changes in files of this gem.

Is there any other adapter for firebird databases for ruby?

Comment: Ok i just reinstall firebird to version: Firebird-2.5.5.26952_0_Win32
now everything works great
close this :)

Comment: You should delete the question yourself.